# Is the ring of Laurent polynomials in $n$ noncommuting variables Noetherian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian

Suppose we have a Noetherian ring $R$. Is it true that the ring of Laurent polynomials $R\langle x_1,\,x_1^{-1},\ldots,\,x_n,\,x_n^{-1}\rangle$ in $n$ noncommuting variables is also Noetherian? If so, why?

Comment: Is it true that the polynomial ring $S=R\langle x_1, x_2, …, x_{n} \rangle$ in $n$ _non-commuting variables_ Noetherian ring?

Answer (score 2):

It's not (left or right) Noetherian if $n>1$ (and $R\neq0$). It's the same as the group ring $RF_n$ of a free group on $n$ generators, and for a group ring to be Noetherian, the group must at least be Noetherian (which $F_n$ is not, since it contains an infinitely generated free subgroup).

To see that $RG$ is not Noetherian if $G$ is not, for any subgroup $H\leq G$, consider the right ideal $I_H$ of $RG$ generated by the augmentation ideal of $RH$ (or equivalently, $I_H$ is the set of $\sum_{g\in G}\lambda_gg\in RG$ such that $\sum_{g\in Hx}\lambda_g=0$ for every coset $Hx$ of $H$ in $G$). Then if $G$ has an infinite ascending chain
$$H_0<H_1<H_2<\dots$$
of subgroups, $RG$ has an infinite ascending chain
$$I_{H_0}<I_{H_1}<I_{H_2}<\dots$$
of right ideals.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a very clear answer. I was wondering if you might also know if there are any conditions on $R[F_n]$ under which this ring becomes countable?

Comment: @SamWilliams Do you mean conditions on $R$? $R[F_n]$ will be countable if and only if $R$ is finite or countable.